# How to prevent floated list elements to wrap

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

How do you make list elements that are floated left next to each other not wrap when the parent div is set to a fixed size?

Moreover, I need the li elements to have the same fixed height. They can have different width.

I'm playing with the [table-cell](http://jsfiddle.net/uhL9e3ec/) display. But it doesn't behave as I want to.

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <ul>
        <li><a><span>gfh gf hfg hf gdfg gdf gdf</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span>dfgdf g dfg dg dfgddfdfdgdf gdfg dfgdf gdf g dfg</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span>dfg dfgdf gdfgdf gdf</span></a></li>
        <li><a><span>Lehce delsi  fghfg hfgdfg dfg d d d</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
}
ul {
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
}
li {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 150px;
}
a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I need to have horizontal scrollbar visible and not the vertical one. Something like this:
[image: Desired behavior]

Answer (score 0):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/uhL9e3ec/1/

set `hover` for `li` because you have styled `li` as `table-cell`

```
li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't solve my problem. I need the li elements to have the same defined height so the #box show its horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: ya i have only changed `a:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}` to `li:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}` @Behnil

Answer (score 0):

To prevent wrapping use:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

On your `ul`

```
ul {
    display: table-row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
    list-style: none;
    white-space:nowrap; /* <--- this */
}
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/m5b8m24u/)

To [**hide the vertical scrollbar**](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/m5b8m24u/1/) add `overflow-y:hidden;` to `#box`, and to setheights, you'll also need to make your inner spans `display:inline-block` so they can hold affixed dimenstions.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The li elements must have the defined height.

Comment: @Behnil....they do? They are all the 50px specified. Can you elaborate specifically what isnt working?

Comment: The text overlaps from one li to another. Take a look at my edited question with an image showing the desired behavior.

Comment: @Behnil - simpyl remove the `max-width` setting from `li`, or add `overflow:hidden` depending on what you want